# Trying to install python3.6 virtualenv on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python

I've recently upgraded my PC from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu20.04 and `virtualenv` stopped working for Pythn3.6.  I discovered Python3.6 was no longer installed but I had done some stuff prior to that.

When I run `virtualenv venv -p python3.6` I now get

> bash: /usr/local/bin/virtualenv: No such file or directory

But if I try to install `virtualenv` it is already installed.

```
henry@henry-DT2216:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualenv
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
virtualenv is already the newest version (20.0.17-1ubuntu0.3).
0 to upgrade, 0 to newly install, 0 to remove and 13 not to upgrade.
```

I have tried purging and reinstalling, but I am now stuck.  Please help

Comment: Try `python3 -m venv venv` to create virtual env

Comment: just try this `virtualenv venv`

Comment: python3 -m venv venv gives   `Error: Command '['/hdd/Documents/Sites/Development/webcdi-temp/venv/bin/python3', '-Im', 'ensurepip', '--upgrade', '--default-pip']' returned non-zero exit status 1.`

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on askubuntu.com

Comment: See [Problem with creating Python 3.6 virtual environment on Ubuntu 20.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231543/problem-with-creating-python-3-6-virtual-environment-on-ubuntu-20-04)

Comment: `virtualenv venv` give : `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenv.seed.via_app_data'`

Comment: I've tried the askubuntu link and it didn't work

Comment: Explain "it didn't work". It worked many times for me.

Comment: I followed the answer exactly and I got the error shown in my question

Comment: I've just followed the alternative approach provided and it worked "As an alternative to step 2 & 3, you could `sudo apt-get install python3.6-venv` and `python3.6 -m venv mypy36venv`"  (although I cannot install a 3.8 venv now!)

Comment: Alternative: you can use the built-in Python3 virtual environment: `python3 -m venv myEnvironment`.